# How to get all combinations of values rowwise in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, permutation

I have a contingency table (ct) like this:

```
read.table( text=     
      1  2  3 4 5 6
1     0  0  1 0 2 0
2     0  0  2 0 0 0
70    0  0  3 0 0 0
76   15 13 19 2 9 8
85    0  0  2 0 0 0
109   0  0  0 0 1 2
479   0  0  0 0 2 0
491   2  0  0 0 0 0
1127  0  1  0 1 6 0
1131  0  1  1 1 2 0
1206  1  3  1 0 0 1
1208  1  0  1 0 0 1
1210  0  1  0 0 0 1
1225  2  0  1 0 0 0
1232  0  0  0 0 1 1
1242  0  0  0 1 0 1
1243  1  0  0 0 1 1
1251  0  0  2 0 1 2
1267  0  2  1 0 0 0
4415  0  2  0 0 0 0
4431  0  0  0 2 0 0
4808  0  0  0 0 2 0
4823  0  2  0 0 0 0 )
```

Where rows represent cluster, columns represent hospitals and numbers in the table the count of isolates.
For example: Cluster 1 has 3 isolates, 1 in hospital 3 and 2 in hospital 2.

I now want to check, if clusters and hospitals are dependent on each other or not. For that, I would like to create 1000 randomly distributed tables, where all isolates in one cluster have the chance to fall into every hospital.
For example: The 3 Isolates in cluster 1 might then be distributed over 3 hospitals, so that I get the values : 0 1 1 1 0 0 .

Combinations can occur multiple times.

I tried this:

```
 replicates <- 1000

 permutations <- lapply(seq(replicates), function(i, ct){
   list <- lapply(apply(ct,1,list),unlist)
   list <- lapply(list, function(x)as.numeric(x))
    z <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(list, function(x) sample(x))))
 }, ct = ct)
```

But by that only the values in the dataframe are shuffled to another position in the row.
Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Provided I understood correctly, I would imagine that this is not a tractable problem; you will have too many combinations per row. 6 numbers can already be re-arranged in 6! = 720 ways, and then we're not yet considering the different possible decompositions of the (row) sums.

Comment: I don't really need all possible combinations. In the end, I would like to have a list of 1000 dataframes where the values in each row were rearranged randomly.

Comment: @Martinique That's not clear to me. So for every row you want to randomly draw 1000 samples from all permutations of the 6 numbers and all permutations of their possible sum decompositions? Is there a preference/bias in whether you sample from the permutations of numbers or the permutations of their sum decompositions? It would be good if you were to re-phrase and clarify your problem statement in the main post (don't add critical information in comments). Please be specific and precise, the devil is in the detail.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I edited the question and hope I could make it a bit more clear what I would like to have..

Comment: *"I now want to check, if clusters and hospitals are dependent on each other or not."* Wouldn't a traditional [chi-square test of independence](https://stattrek.com/chi-square-test/independence.aspx) help you answer that question? I don't see why you need to come up with a custom permutation-based test here.

Comment: Because less than 80% of the cells in my table are under the value of 5, which, to my knowledge, is an assumption for this test. I also tried the Fishers exact test as an alternative, but we wanted to have a different approach for this analysis. That's why I wanted to create permutations on my own. However, I also need to manipulate tables for other analyses in that way

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Maurits Evers answer, at full rank you got binomial combination per lines : n variables mean 2^n combination... if you add m-1 columns this yields 2^(n+m) possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using `partitions::composition`.

```
library(partitions)

# smaller toy data
d <- data.frame(x1 = c(0, 1, 1), x2 = c(2, 2, 0), x3 = c(0, 1, 1))

# calculate row sums
rs <- rowSums(d)

# for each unique row sum, partition the value with order m = number of columns
# this avoids repeating calculation of partitions on duplicate row sums
l <- lapply(unique(rs), compositions, m = ncol(d))

# name list elements with row sums
names(l) <- unique(rs)

# set number of samples
n <- 4

# to reproduce sample in this example  
set.seed(1)

# loop over rows in data frame
lapply(1:nrow(d), function(i){

  # index list of partitions using row sums
  m <- l[[as.character(rs[i])]]

  # number of columns to sample from
  nc <- ncol(m)

  # select columns from matrix using a sample of n column indexes
  m[ , sample(nc, n, replace = TRUE)]
})
```

The result is a list where each element is a matrix for each row of the original data. Each matrix column is one (sampled) partition.

```
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    0    1    0
# [2,]    1    2    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    1    2
# 
# [[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    0    0    2
# [2,]    3    1    0    0
# [3,]    0    3    4    2
# 
# [[3]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    2    1    1
# [2,]    0    0    1    1
# [3,]    1    0    0    0
```

---

I tried to partition the largest row sum in your example data (66), and it runs pretty quickly. Thus, if your row sums are not very much larger and the number of columns is small (like here), the code above may be a viable option.

```
system.time(p <- compositions(66, 6))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.53    0.16    1.68 
str(p)
# 'partition' int [1:6, 1:13019909] 66 0 0 0 0 0 65 1 0 0 ...
```

Note that it 'explodes' rapidly if the number of columns increases:

```
system.time(p <- compositions(66, 7))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   14.11    1.61   15.72
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort! It really helped a lot!

Comment: Hi @Martinique Thanks for your feedback. Curious to hear how (if...) it worked on your real data. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry @Henrik for the late response. Your code worked out quite well for me! However, with the help of a colleague of mine, I figured out this code (I'll just show it using your sample data):

```
#data
d <- data.frame(x1 = c(0, 1, 1), x2 = c(2, 2, 0), x3 = c(0, 1, 1))
#Number of replicates I want
replicates <- 1000
#Number of columns in the table 
k<- 3

l <- NULL

#unlist the dataframe
list <- lapply(apply(d,1,list),unlist)

#Calculate replicates of the dataframe, where numbers are permuted within rows

permutations <- lapply(seq(replicates), function(j){
        l_sampled <- lapply(list, function(x){
          pos.random <- sample(k, sum(x), replace = T) 
          x.random <- rep(0,k)                        
          for (i in 1:k){
            x.random[i] <- sum(pos.random==i)
          }
          l = rbind(l, data.frame(x.random)) 
        })
        df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(l_sampled), nrow=length(l_sampled), byrow=T))
})

#Example for results:

> permutations[[8]]
  X1 X2 X3
1  2  0  0
2  1  2  1
3  1  0  1
> permutations[[10]]
  X1 X2 X3
1  0  1  1
2  2  0  2
3  0  2  0
```